# Calling asynchronous function synchronously is more responsive

Tags: winforms, asynchronous, async-await, event-handling, .net-5

I have an asynchronous method like this:

```
private async Task TaskAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(2000));
}
```

I then call it in a button-click event, which I've declared like this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await TaskAsync();

    MessageBox.Show("Afterwards.");
}
```

Now, when I click on the button, `TaskAsync()` is literally awaited on, and the message box isn't shown until `TaskAsync()` has finished executing. However, when I remove the `await` command when calling `TaskAsync()` in the click event, then execution immediately jumps to the message box.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this normal behavior of async...await?

My project is a .NET Core 5 C# winform project.

Comment: Two things are wrong. First, the `TaskAsync` method is using `Task.Run` to run *another* async method. That just wastes a thread. It should be just `await Task.Delay(2000);`. Second, if you don't await a task execution will proceed immediatelly. That's the whole point of using `await` - awaiting an already esecuting asynchronous task to complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.  First, the `TaskAsync` method is using `Task.Run` to run *another* async method. That just wastes a thread. It should be just :

```
private async Task TaskAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}
```

if not

```
private Task TaskAsync()=>Task.Delay(2000);
```

Second, if a Task isn't awaited execution will proceed immediately. That's the whole point of using `await` - awaiting an already executing asynchronous task to complete *without* blocking the calling thread.

The original code is equivalent to :

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    MessageBox.Show("Afterwards.");
}
```

Without `await`, the task returned by `Task.Delay()` will be ignored and the message box will be displayed immediately.

If one wanted to start a long operation, eg reading a big file, and display a message at the same time, the task can be stored in a field and awaited *after* the dialog box is closed:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task=File.ReadAllTextAsync(...);
    MessageBox.Show("Reading a file");
    var text=await task;
    MessageBox.Show("Afterwards.");
}
```

or

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task=Task.Run(()=>SomeBackgroundProcessing(someArgs));
    MessageBox.Show("Processing");
    var text=await task;
    MessageBox.Show("Afterwards.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @PanagiotisKanavos. Yes, I've realized now how async-await works. I'm just used to using Threads and having execution go immediately to the next statement; I'll have to get used to this. Also, the reason for the `await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(2000));` is that it's a quick cut-down version of real code. :)

Comment: @ocm in that case you should post the *real* code. A lot of APIs have async alternatives, especially the IO-related methods (eg HttpClient.GetAsync, EF's ToListAsync()`. Blocking with `async` in WinForms can be solved with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. `Task.Run` is typically needed for the CPU-bound part of a method.

Comment: @ocm concurrency with threads is hard when you have to juggle more than 2 or 3 operations - besides IO doesn't need threads. That's why a *lot* of languages have adopted promises, futures and even the `async/await` keywords to hide this complexity, eg JavaScript, Kotlin, C++, Rust.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, it's not important about what `TaskAsync()` was really meant to do, my problem was needing the next statement (showing a message box, in my sample) to execute concurrently. I don't agree that IO doesn't need threads. Threads are simply a way to handle concurrency, and it's up to the user to use them or async-await.

Comment: @ocm I'm not talking about how the code calls an IO operation. IO means you're always waiting on something else to respond, so there's no need for an active thread to do anything. The CPU just waits. On Windows, the OS itself always uses async IO and callbacks instead of blocking threads. Blocking operations are simulated. When you read a file or make an HTTP call the OS will start the operation and return immediately. When that operation completes it will call a callback method.

Comment: A great explanation is given by Stephen Cleary in [There is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).  This is alsoo described in the Windows docs in [Synchronous and Asynchronous IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o). Windows also uses [IO Completion ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) to allow issuing multiple IO operations concurrently. *Some database drivers fake async though* eg Oracle's ODP.NET, in which case you still have to use `Task.Run`